# How to open any random app from device in a react native app like clash royale pubg COD?

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I have been going through Linking.openUrl() in react native which contains a deepLink or path may be. Its ok for app like whatsaap and playstore but how can it be done for opening any random app in react native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this to open clashroyale from my react native app.

```
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking
} from 'react-native';


<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL(`clashroyale://`)}><Text>Open clash royale</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```

So basically all you need to find is the deep link url for the app. like here clashroyale has `clashroyale://` , so similarly if you find the urls then just add them in Linkinh.openURL and it should work. 
Hope it helps.Ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so how did you find the deep link of clashRoyale.

Comment: glad it helped :)